# Codeigniter Illegal string offset server issue in PostgreSQL query

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

we are using PostGreSql database, when we run following code unit, it shows error of.

```
 Severity: Warning
 Message: Illegal string offset 'server'
 Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php


Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at       system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
```

**Model Code:**

```
public function tracks_add( $id ) {
    $cnt = 0;
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $s_title = $this->input->post('s_title');
    $s_singer = $this->input->post('s_singer');
    $s_url = $this->input->post('s_url');

    foreach ($s_title as $s_title) {
        $this->db->set( array('a_id'=> $id, 's_title' => $s_title, 's_singer' => $s_singer[$cnt], 's_url' => $s_url[$cnt], 'date'=> $date) );
        $this->db->insert('soundtracks');

        $cnt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's telling you that there is no index 'server' available.   You're probably supposed to set $something['server'] before calling some other function.
And then it's telling you that you can't specify headers after you've already output (some of) the body, i.e. the error message.

Answer (score 6):

You can find this issue here :
[Postgres db driver insert issue](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1583)

Change line 331 to

```
$v = pg_version($this->conn_id); $v = isset($v['server']) ? $v['server'] : 0; // 'server' key
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! Any idea what the f*** is going on with that bug? It seems like it's existed for several versions of CI... maybe no one is using postgres?

Comment: Works fine for me! Thumbs up. Thanks a lot.